# Canvas to PDF without javascript

Tags: pdf, canvas

I have a problem. I make diagramms using Canvas and Javascript. Is there a way to convert the website into a PDF file without javascript activated from the client. So I produce the PDF on the server. It would be also possible if I can make a picture from the website.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying that you are creating a canvas using JavaScript yet the client does not have JavaScript activated?

Comment: If you are trying to do something without javascript, then don't tag javascript.

Comment: If you're creating something via javascript, you need javascript (be it on server or client) to know how it looks like. Period.

Comment: I have a website running on a XAMPP server. At the result page i use canvas and a JS file called chart.js to generate chart. But if the client doesnt have javascript the diagramms are not displayed. So i want to offer the client, who has no javascript, a PDF with the charts in it. For this i have to render the website but if the client has no javascript i cant make the PDF. And now i need your help to generate the PDF without the clients javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Could you pass the HTML through [wkhtmltopdf](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) on your server?

wkhtmltopdf renders your page using WebKit, including executing JavaScript, and writes the result into a PDF.

You run it on the command line like this:

```
wkhtmltopdf my.html my.pdf
```

Comment: The problem is that it only works with HTML File and i have a .php file.

Comment: @OliverAdam: It also works with a URL, eg. `wkhtmltopdf http://myserver.com/mypage.php my.pdf`

Comment: @OliverAdam: Via the `system()` function maybe?